# En GitHub Pages no me cargan las imágenes de mi archivo app.js

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

Construí mi primera galería de imágenes en HTML,CSS y JavaScript. El código podéis verlo en el siguiente repositorio:

- https://github.com/ZASKE99/mi-primera-galeria/

Todo funciona bien de manera local (en el live server de Visual Studio Code en un sistema operativo Windows) pero a la hora de subirlo a GitHub y desplegarlo en GitHub Pages las imágenes no cargan cuando se le da clic, como deberían.

Éste es el enlace a la página en GitHub Pages:

- https://zaske99.github.io/mi-primera-galeria/

Sé que el error debe estar en la línea 12 del archivo `app.js`. Intente colocar el "./", "../", "/.", pero nada ha funcionado:

[image: Captura de pantalla de la imagen en local]

Funcionamiento Local ☝

En Git Hub Pages

[image: Captura de pantalla de la imagen en GitHub Pages]

Errores que aparecen al darle clic en GitHub Pages

[image: Error en la consola de JavaScript en GitHub Pages]

El error debe estar ahí, ¿no?

[image: Captura de pantalla del código fuente]

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el código? Nos vendría bien conocer el repositorio github y el enlace de github pages para poder ver qué está pasando.

Comment: Ya he encontrado el problema. Según parece estás usando Windows para desarrollar la página (mala idea), por lo que no has sido consciente de que no coinciden las mayúsculas/minúsculas de las rutas. Te mando petición de mezcla y redacto respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que no coinciden las mayúsculas/minúsculas de la imagen que deseas mostrar.

En un sistema operativo insensible a ellas, como Windows, la página web se mostrará correctamente, pero en cualquier otro sistema operativo (AIX, Linux, MacOS, FreeBSD, etc) no se encontrará el archivo.

Esta es la [línea del script](https://github.com/ZASKE99/mi-primera-galeria/blob/d411a784aeddbd6ebc8ab7410a830c66dd5f720c/app.js#L12):

```
images.forEach((img, index) => {
    img.addEventListener('click', () => {
        openModal(`./images/img${index}.jpg`) // <-- Aquí está la errata
    })
})
```

La imagen está localizada en [`Images/img2.jpg`](https://github.com/ZASKE99/mi-primera-galeria/blob/d411a784aeddbd6ebc8ab7410a830c66dd5f720c/Images/img2.jpg).

Te he enviado una petición de mezcla para corregir la ruta en el código:

- [Corregida ruta de la imagen #1](https://github.com/ZASKE99/mi-primera-galeria/pull/1).

El cambio consiste en esta diferencia:

```
- openModal(`./images/img${index}.jpg`)
+ openModal(`Images/img${index}.jpg`)
```

Comment: ¡Era exactamente eso, tendré en cuenta esto para futuros proyectos, muchas gracias, Oscar!